# replace an item in a html tag spanning multiple lines

Tags: python, regex, replace

I have a text file with html:

```
Blah, blah, blah

some text is here.

<div> something here

something else </body></html>
```

so far, if the tags are on one line this works:

```
textfile = open("htmlfile.txt", "r+")

text = textfile.read()

a = re.search('<div.+?<\/html>', text)

repstr = c.group(0)

text = text.replace(repstr, '', 1)
```

works fine, I don't have nested tags.
But if the tags are on multiple lines, like the first example, it doesn't work! what can I use to test multiple lines?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, the dot doesn't match new lines. To make it match new lines, you need to compile the regex with the flag [`re.DOTALL`](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#re.DOTALL), eg:

```
a = re.search('<div.+?<\/html>', text, re.DOTALL)
```

---

That being said, you really [shouldn't use regex to parse HTML.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454)

Do yourself a favor and use an XML parser like [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/).

Comment: oh, I see. My project is fairly simple and doesn't really require Beautifulsoup, but ill keep that in mind. Thanks!